# JSON parsing in android appilication

Tags: android, json

I am new to android, I have `JSON` object how to parse my `JSONarray`

```
[
    {
        "Men":,
        "shirts": [
            {
                "name":"ABC",
                "image":"http://domain.com/image.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name":"USA",
                "image":"imageURLg"
            }
        ],
        "Pants": [
            {
                "name":"sample",
                "image":"imageurl"
            },
            {
                "name":"shoper",
                "image":"imageurl"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

please tell me how to split my array in to  categories

Comment: First, post a Json with valid format.

Comment: Like @Rami said, post the formatted json. Use JsonArray class to parse.JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jsonObjectName);

Comment: Your JSON was completely invalid, but you would notice that if you format it properly. It was missing colons between the elements and also some brackets were missing.

Answer (score 0):

Easy trick for json parsing:

where you find this opening brace "{" ,then get JsonObject.

and where you find this opening brace "[" ,then get JsonArray.

Comment: Found this answer helping?? please mention. if not then also comment .so, we can provide you further help.

Comment: help me how to slip my json array in to categories @israr ahmad

Answer (score 0):

To parse your JSON, that starts with "[" use the JSONArray class.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray (response)
```

Iterate in the array object to get item by item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    value = row.getString(TAG);
}
```

This is a very complete tutorial about JSON parsing:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(here give the name of your json string);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("shirts"));
```

then loop through the **jsonArray**.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON was invalid. Make sure you always check your JSON in [Validating JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) .This is how you can split it into categories with modified JSON:

```
String jsonString = "[\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"Men\": \"\",\n" +
                "        \"shirts\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"name\": \"ABC\",\n" +
                "                \"image\": \"http://domain.com/image.jpg\"\n" +
                "            },\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"name\": \"USA\",\n" +
                "                \"image\": \"imageURLg\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        ],\n" +
                "        \"Pants\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"name\": \"sample\",\n" +
                "                \"image\": \"imageurl\"\n" +
                "            },\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"name\": \"shoper\",\n" +
                "                \"image\": \"imageurl\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "]";
        try{
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            //Get the shirts
            JSONArray shirtsArray = array.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("shirts");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"shirtsArray = " + shirtsArray.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < shirtsArray.length(); i++){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "name = " + shirtsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")+" image: "+shirtsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
            }
            //Get the pants
            JSONArray pantsArray = array.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Pants");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"shirtsArray = " + shirtsArray.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < pantsArray.length(); i++){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "name = " + pantsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")+" image: "+pantsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
            }
        }catch (JSONException ex){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
        }
```